# MySQL Select data from multiple dates using a loop

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate the survival rate of various products, which I will define as making it 90 days without requiring any repairs.

Using essentially the query below, I was able to pull the data as of today. I would like to be able to run the query on every day of this year.

I have 2 tables. One that contains every widget, and a second that contains a list of repairs. I join the two tables together and look for records less than 90 days old.

I read through lots of examples on line, and thought this would would work, but it won't run. Any suggestions on how to fix this query, or a better way of getting this information would be appreciated.

```
set @BeginDate = '01/01/2014', @EndDate = CURDATE();

Create Procedure dowhile()

Begin

While @BeginDate <= @EndDate Do
 SELECT
    All_Widgets.widget_name, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(All_Widgets.id_num)) AS Total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(Repaired_Widgets.id_num)) AS Repaired,
    100 - ((COUNT(DISTINCT(All_Widgets.id_num)) / COUNT(DISTINCT(Repaired_Widgets.id_num)) * 100)) AS survival_rate,
    @BeginDate, @EndDate
FROM All_Widgets
LEFT JOIN Repaired_Widgets ON (All_Widgets.hw_id = ammunition_repair_records.hw_id)
WHERE DATEDIFF(@BeginDate, All_Widgets.timestamp) <= 90
GROUP BY All_Widgets.widget_name

set @BeginDate = DateAdd(@BeginDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);

End While;
End
```

Comment: why a loop? why not just `... where begindate >= (curdate() - INTERVAL 90 DAY)`?

Comment: For each date, I will get a survival rate for each product. I want to know how that rate varies over the course of the year. If I look at a single date, I only get a snapshot. I hope this clarifies. Thanks for taking a look.